# Access and aggregate choices from different classes django

Tags: python, django

Here is what I have:

```
class Service(models.Model):
SERVICE_UNITY_TYPE = (
    ('H', 'Hours'),
    ('DAY', 'Days'),
    ('MON', 'Months'),
    ('WEE', 'Weeks')
)

class Product(models.Model):
PRODUCT_UNITY_TYPE = (
    ('CM', 'Centimeter'),
    ('M', 'Meter'),
    ('KM', 'Kilometers'),
    ('M2', 'Square Meter'),
    ('M3', 'Cubic Meters'),
    ('KG', 'Kilogram'),
    ('BOX', 'Boxes'),
    ('LT', 'Liters'),
    ('QTY', 'Qty'),
)
```

What I want is to aggregate the two choices from these classes to another class:

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):

```
ITEM_TYPE = (
    Product.PRODUCT_UNITY_TYPE,
    Service.SERVICE_UNITY_TYPE,
)

type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ITEM_TYPE)
```

OR even better, if this was possible:

```
type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(Product.PRODUCT_UNITY_TYPE, Service.SERVICE_UNITY_TYPE))
```

Comment: Could you not just add those two lists, i.e. choices=Product.PRODUCT_UNITY_TYPE+Service.SERVICE_UNITY_TYPE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
combined_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=Product.PRODUCT_UNITY_TYPE + Service.SERVICE_UNITY_TYPE,
)
```

(but "MON" won't fit in your "max_length=2" field, so you might want to change that as well)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. About the attribute, yes, it was just a test I was performing before. I will change that :)